# Override toString() for swing classes

Tags: java, swing

I want to override toString() method for a FileFilter object.
I have this piece of code

```
JFileChooser saveFile = new JFileChooser();
saveFile.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
saveFile.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
saveFile.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("PNG", ".png"));
String type = saveFile.getFileFilter().toString();
System.out.println(type);
```

Which prints out something along the lines of `javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter@39cc65b1[description=PNG extensions=[.png]]`. My goal is to create an overridden toString method, so I would get only the `.png` part. 
I KNOW that there are more efficient ways to do this exact task, and I know the basic string functions to get the part I need, but my goal is to do it with an overridden method.

Comment: Create a class extending JFileChooser and override toString()

Comment: Have you tried using FileFilter.getDescription()? If you don't want to do the cast, you need to subclass FileNameExtensionFilter and override toString there.

Comment: "I know the basic string functions to get the part I need" - why don't you use that? Why do you want to override a method (which is impossible since the class is final).

Comment: @Tokazio No, don't extend JFileChooser - the toString() method in question is that of the chooser's FileFilter, so you need to create a subclass of FileFilter, not JFileChooser.

Comment: @FredK, ok your right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my goal is to do it with an overridden method.

This is not possible, for a number of reasons described below. The only way to do it is through composition, not through inheritance.

You can override a method only in classes that you own. Since you do not own the `FileNameExtensionFilter`, an implementation of `FileFilter` returned by `JFileChooser`, there is no way for you to override its `toString` method.

Moreover, [`FileNameExtensionFilter` is a `final` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html), so you cannot override any of its methods.

The only approach available in this situation is to create your own `FileFilter` wrapping `FileNameExtensionFilter`, and pass it the filter that you get from `JFileChooser`. You would own this class, so you could override its `toString` as needed:

```
class FileFilterWrapper {

    private final FileFilter innerFilter;

    public FileFilterWrapper(FileFilter innerFilter) {
        this.innerFilter = innerFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        // Use innerFilter properties to produce the desired String
        return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: As a final class, you can not extend FileNameExtensionFIlter either.  Thus the statement "only way to do it is through composition"

Comment: @DwB Right, that's what the "Moreover, ..." paragraph is saying.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Could you elaborate on your last paragraph? I understand your explanation in general, but I'm oblivious as of how to create a class "wrapping `FileNameExtensionFilter`"

Answer (score 2):

If you literally just want to do it right here you could do an anonymous inner class for it:

```
JFileChooser saveFile = new JFileChooser() {
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return ".png";
   }
}
```

I can't recommend that approach though, it would be better to implement your own subclass of `JFileChooser` and define a new `String getFileExtension()` method inside that.

Answer (score 2):

To do that, you need to use a subclass of JFileChooser. If that's the only method you want to override, its quite simple.

```
public class MyFileChooser extends JFileChooser{
    public MyFileChooser(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        //your string conversion code here
    }
}
```